# Orthocentre of a triangle

Tags: triangles

I just want to know what the orthocentre of a triangle is? How do you define it?  It appears in a past paper so i just need the definition.  Thanks!

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Orthocenter.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The orthocenter is the point of concurrency where the lines containing the three altitudes of the triangle intersect.

Comment: I thought that was the centroid?

Comment: The centroid is the point where the medians of the triangle intersect.

Comment: Ahh now I understand.  Thanks so much :)